# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 5} (6-x)^{1/(x-5)}$ ??

Tags: real-analysis

Help evaluating the following limit?

$$\lim_{x\to 5} (6-x)^{1/(x-5)}$$

My attempt: 
$$\lim_{x\to 5} (6-x)^{1/(x-5)}
= \lim_{x\to 5} (6-5)^{1/(5-5)}=1^{\infty}=1.$$

Comment: Try the substitution $y={1 \over 5-x}$

Comment: Hint: You can write $6-x = 1 - (x-5)$.

Comment: $1^{\infty} \ne 1$.

Comment: Your title asks about a different limit from your question body. Which one of them are you asking about? Also, you can't just conclude automatically that a $1^\infty$ type limit is equal to $1$. For instance, $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac1x)^x$ is of that type, and it's famously not equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$lim_{x\rightarrow 5} (6-x)^\frac{1}{x-5}$$
$$lim_{x\rightarrow 5} e^{\cfrac{\ln {(6-x)}}{x-5}}$$
$$lim_{x\rightarrow 5} e^{\cfrac{\ln ({1-(x-5)})}{x-5}}$$